# Value Counts of all columns in a df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a **df** such as:

```
Monday | Tuesday | Friday | January  | Weekday 
True      False     True     False      True
False     False     False    False      False
True      True      False    False      True
False     False     False    False      False
```

I want to calculate the % that each column has True and False, typically I would use a value counts with a normalize parameter below as:

```
df['Monday'].value_counts(normalize = True)
```

**Output:**

```
Monday 
True   .5
False  .5
```

But how can I run the same code where it would give me that % for **all** columns in the df, instead of doing it manually per column?

Thanks!

Comment: You have typo 'Fasle' vs 'False' in three position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, use `pd.dataframe.apply` to apply the `pd.Series.value_counts` function passing `normalize=True` as a parameter to the apply function:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
       Monday  Tuesday  Friday  January  Weekday
False     0.5     0.75    0.75      1.0      0.5
True      0.5     0.25    0.25      0.0      0.5
```

Comment: Thanks this works as well as Danis answer below is it possible to accept both answers? Thank you - also these are the only 2 answers here that give correct expected output. They both have the fillna(0) parameter like you have  -  is it possible I can understand why it is needed for correct output? Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Chris90 January has no True values, therefore value_counts doesn't return anything for a series that doesn't have the values, so, when apply assembles the dataframe using indexes, there is a NaN for True and January.  We use fillna to make that missing value a zero.

Answer (score 3):

apply value value_counts to the dataframe . Groupby the resulting dataframe's index and sum

```
g=df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).value_counts(normalize=True))
g.groupby(g.index).sum()



     Monday  Tuesday  Friday  January  Weekday
False     0.5     0.75    0.75      1.0      0.5
True      0.5     0.25    0.25      0.0      0.5
```

Comment: This gives a third row in the output called nan ? 

False 0.931633 0.804139
True 0.038803 0.195861
nan 0.029564 0.000000

Comment: @Chris90 because some of your `False` are not properly spelled

Answer (score 2):

You could apply it to each column and then concat (with [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)) the results:

```
res = pd.concat((df[col].value_counts(normalize=True) for col in df.columns), axis=1).fillna(0)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
       Monday  Tuesday  Friday  January  Weekday
True      0.5     0.25    0.25      0.0      0.5
False     0.5     0.75    0.75      1.0      0.5
```

Use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), to fill the cells of columns where some values are missing, for example, the *True* value is missing from the *January* column.

Comment: Thanks, what does the fillna here do? was wondering why that is needed @Dani Mesejo

Comment: @Chris90 All values for January are False, so when you do the concat the value for True at January is Nan, hence fillna

Answer (score -4):

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True).fillna(0)
```

This should work.

Comment: Gives TypeError: value_counts() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Nope, you can't pass a parameter like this in pandas.